# Why vector cannot insert class with this copy constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class dog {
public:
    dog() {}
    dog(dog & d) {
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<dog> vec;
    dog d;
    vec.push_back(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I can not insert dog into the vector. The problem lies in the copy constructor. If I add const in the copy constructor, the code compiles. I just wonder why I have to add const in the copy constructor.

The error message is:

> error: binding ‘const dog’ to reference of type ‘dog&’ discards qualifiers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602058/why-is-the-copy-constructor-argument-const

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441067/c-push-back-non-const-copy-constructor

Comment: Hey, new duplicate list editing feature is cool

Answer (score 1):

[std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) takes `const T&` as its parameter (for lvalue), that means when it's called the argument will be bound to the parameter with type `const dog&`, which will be used to construct `dog` inside the `vector` later (in `push_back`).

For such copy construction to be achieved, the appropriate copy constructor (i.e. `dog::dog(const dog&)` is needed; but the signature of the copy constructor is `dog::dog(dog&)`, which can't take a `const dog&`, thus the compiler failed to find the appropriate copy constructor to perform the operation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes it was not clear enough; anyway I tried to make it more clear.